# Cannot login to local database using web service

Tags: c#, sql-server, web-services

I am trying to access my local database using a web service also running locally on the Default Website in IIS7. I previously always used Windows Authentication but I read that to use web services you have to use SQL Server authentication, I have no experience with this but tried it out. I created a new login, but when I try using those credentials in my connection string:

```
connectionString="Server=.\SQLExpress;Database='SponsorChild';Trusted_Connection=True;User Id=abc;Password=abcpass" name="SponsorChildDatabase"/>
```

and try using the web service, I get the error:

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Cannot open database &quot;SponsorChild&quot; requested by the login. The login failed.
Login failed for user &#39;IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool&#39;.
```

So it seems not even the right user is being passed. Moreover, when I try logging in using SQL Management Studio, it also gives me a login error ([error 18456 with state 38](http://www.eraofdata.com/blog/sql-18456-login-failures/)). I apologize if this is just some rookie mistake, but I'm just starting out with databases and website building and still have a lot to learn. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Since your application is running under IIS, and the error implies that it tries to connect with IIS pool account, it seems something wrong with your sqlconnection. Can you provide the connection code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Trusted_Connection=True` uses the Windows credentials and not the provided username and password. The user you've setup in the database doesn't play a role. You either need to use SQL Server auth or authenticate the Windows account the service is running under.

This is a sample connectionstirng not using Windows credentials:

```
Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;User ID=myUsername;Password=myPassword;Trusted_Connection=False;
```

Comment: The web service is at least opening the database, it still won't let me login with the user I created, but your answer solves the problem I posed in my question. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

### To create a SQL Server login that uses SQL Server Authentication (SQL Server Management Studio)

> 1.In SQL Server Management Studio, open Object Explorer and expand the folder of the server instance in which to create the new login.
>
> 2.Right-click the Security folder, point to New, and then click Login.
>
> 3.On the General page, enter a name for the new login in the Login name box.
>
> 4.Select SQL Server Authentication. Windows Authentication is the more secure option.
>
> 5.Enter a password for the login.
>
> 6.Select the password policy options that should be applied to the new login. In general, enforcing password policy is the more secure
>   option.
>
> 7.Click OK.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that the database is local probably means you administer it yourself, so [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337562.aspx) is a manual for setting the sql server authentication.

Answer (score 0):

Check to make sure:

that you have the proper server name in your connection string. Is it really localhost? Or did you perhaps install SQL Server Express and it ended up being (local)\SQLExpress instead??

that the server you're connecting to has a login for User-Desktop\user(check in Object Explorer -> (your server) -> Security -> Logins)

that the database ASPNETDB has a user based on that login so that you can use that database (check in Object Explorer -> (your server) -> Databases -> (your database) -> Security -> Users)

that your admin.aspx page is truly referencing that connection string you've given (ConnectionString1). Is there by any chance a separate web.config in your Admin folder that e.g. has a different connection string, and the admin.aspx page references that connection string instead??

Comment: The second one seems to be true, I have a user - "Matt-PC\Matt" why would this affect the other login?